# Boolean Function Giving a Seg Fault

Tags: c++, class, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm attempting to make DFA for all possible moves in a Tictactoe game. When I call my firstMove() function the second time around I get a seg fault and I'm not sure why.

This is my States.hpp File.

```
#ifndef STATE_HPP
#define STATE_HPP

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 class State{
 public:
  State();
  State(State *s);
  //~State;                                                                                                                                              
  State getState();
  void setStateChildren(State *s);
  vector<State*> *getChildren();
  void setFirstMove(bool b);
  void setPosition(int *p[]);
  void setfirst();
  void setFirstMove();
  bool firstMove();
  string getFirstPlayer();
  int *position();
  bool isFinal();
  bool isReject();
  void setFinal(bool f);
  void setReject(bool r);
  void print();
 private:
  bool final;
  bool reject;
  bool firstPlayerMove;
 // bool tie;                                                                                                                                           
 //  vector<int> * _position;                                                                                                                           
  int *_position = new int[9];// = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};                                                                                          
  vector<State *> *_children;
};



#endif
```

This is my States.cpp File.

```
State::State(){
  final = false;
  reject = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    _position[i] = 2;
  firstPlayerMove = true;
  _children = new vector<State *> ();
};

State::State(State *s){
  this->final = s->final;
  for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  this->_position[i] = s->_position[i];
  firstPlayerMove = false;
  // this->firstPlayerMove = s->firstPlayerMove;                                                                                                         
  this->_children = s->_children;
  final = false;
  reject = false;
}

void State::setStateChildren(State *s){
  _children->push_back(s);
}
vector<State*> *State::getChildren(){
  return _children;

}

void State::setFirstMove(bool b){
  firstPlayerMove = b;
}

bool State::firstMove(){
  return firstPlayerMove;
}

void State::setPosition(int *p[]){

  //  cout << *_position[0] << endl;                                                                                                                     
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    cout << *p[i] << endl;
    _position[i] = *p[i];
  }
  //_position = p;                                                                                                                                       
}

int *State::position(){
  return _position;
}

bool State::isFinal(){
  return final;
}

bool State::isReject(){
  return reject;
}

void State::setFinal(bool f){
  final = f;
}

void State::setReject(bool r){
  reject = r;
}

void State::print(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    cout << "Position " << i << ": " << _position[i] << endl;
  if (firstPlayerMove)
    cout << "Yes" << endl;
  else
    cout << "No" << endl;
```

}

This is my Main.cpp

```
void CreateDFA(State *state, int n){
  bool first;
  dependents(state, state->firstMove());
  if (n == 0)
    return;
  if (state->isFinal())
    return;
  if (state->isReject())
    return;
  cout << "State Parent " << endl;
  state->print();
  for (vector<State*>::iterator iter = state->getChildren()->begin(); iter !=    state->getChildren()->end(); iter++){
     cout << " In iteration of children" << endl;
     cout << "State Child" << endl;
     (*iter)->print();
     first =  (*iter)->firstMove();
     dependents(*iter, first);
     CreateDFA(*iter, n - 1);
       }
 }

void dependents(State *state, bool first){
  cout << "In dependents" << endl;
  int symbol;
  if (first == true)
    symbol = 1;
  else
    symbol = 0;
  int count = 0;
  while (count < 3){
     if (state->position()[count] == 2){
  // If move is blank, it creates a new State called child and changes that position to the symbol                                                   
  // then adds that child to state's children                                                                                                        
     State *child = new State(state);
     child->setFirstMove(!(first));
     child->position()[count] = symbol;
     state->setStateChildren(child);
   }
  count++;
  }
}

int main(){
  State * s = new State();
  CreateDFA(s, 3);

  return 0;
}
```

This is what is printing
    In dependents
    State Parent 
    Position 0: 2
    Position 1: 2
    Position 2: 2
    Position 3: 2
    Position 4: 2
    Position 5: 2
    Position 6: 2
    Position 7: 2
    Position 8: 2
    Yes
    In iteration of children
    State Child
    Position 0: 1
    Position 1: 2
    Position 2: 2
    Position 3: 2
    Position 4: 2
    Position 5: 2
    Position 6: 2
    Position 7: 2
    Position 8: 2
     No
    In dependents
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)

This is the error when I debug

```
0x0000000000400e14 in State::firstMove (this=0x0) at States.cpp:36
36    return firstPlayerMove;

#0  0x0000000000400e14 in State::firstMove (this=0x0) at States.cpp:36
#1  0x0000000000401a20 in CreateDFA (state=0x0, n=2) at Main.cpp:16
#2  0x0000000000401b77 in CreateDFA (state=0x615c20, n=3) at Main.cpp:30
#3  0x0000000000401ce2 in main () at Main.cpp:67
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: nothing jumps out at me -- post the full code that can reproduce the problem and a stack trace from the debugger when it crashes, please

Comment: Cannot access memory at address 0x2

Comment: your copy constructor isn't right, but that's not causing your crash: State::State(State *s) should be State::State(const State & s)

Comment: what's the rest of the stack trace? as in what called that funciton?   what called THAT function, etc..

Comment: also, don't dynamically allocate _children.   Just put the actual type in your class, not a pointer to vector<State*>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "copy constructor", you say:

```
this->_children = s->_children;
```

but because `_children` is a pointer to a vector (not an actual vector), it simply has both State objects pointing to the same vector.  When you change one, it changes the other.

Changing `_children` from `vector<state>*` to `vector<state>` in `State` should solve your problem.

While you're at it, make it a proper copy constructor by changing it to `State::State(const State & s)`.  Also, make `position` a static array, as well:  `int position[9]`

Comment: Is it okay to keep vector<State*> _children

Comment: yes, that is what you want.   But do you really want to make a copy of the parent on this line: `State *child = new State(state);` or do you want a fresh State object?   If you copy the _children vector, your child will have the same children as whatever the parent has when the copy is made (though subsequent changes won't be shared)

Comment: I do want new State object, but I want the values of the parent object set to the new State object. I don't need the _children from parent to be in the new object though. Would that still be a copy constructor?

Comment: No, you wouldn't want that.  A copy constructor should make a copy - not a "somewhat similar" object.   So in this case I wouldn't change it from state* to const state &, but you don't want to copy the vector, so (assuming you made it a vector<State> instead of vector<State>*), you just don't do anything at all to _children and it will be empty